# Makefile: wget: operation not permitted only on GitLab CI job

Tags: docker, docker-compose, makefile, gitlab-ci, wget

I have a Makefile containing the following:

```
docker-compose.yml:
    wget https://gitlab.com/dependabot-gitlab/dependabot/-/raw/v0.34.0/docker-compose.yml
    docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:${PWD} -w ${PWD} mikefarah/yq:3 yq delete -i docker-compose.yml 'services[*].ports'
```

Running `make docker-compose.yml` works as expected, downloading and hacking the targeted docker-compose.yml remote file.

However, if I configure a GitLab CI job to run this command:

```yaml
deploy:
  image: docker:20.10
  services:
    - docker:20.10-dind
  before_script:
    - apk add make wget
    - make docker-compose.yml
  script: docker-compose up -d
```

I have the following error:

```
$ make docker-compose.yml
wget https://gitlab.com/dependabot-gitlab/dependabot/-/raw/v0.34.0/docker-compose.yml
make: wget: Operation not permitted
make: *** [Makefile:5: docker-compose.yml] Error 127
```

But copy pasting the `make docker-compose.yml` command contents directly to the CI job script like so:

```yaml
deploy:
  # ...
  before_script:
    - apk add wget
    # Copy of make docker-compose.yml
    # For "reasons", using the make command end to a "wget: Operation not permitted" error.
    - wget https://gitlab.com/dependabot-gitlab/dependabot/-/raw/v0.34.0/docker-compose.yml
    - docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:${PWD} -w ${PWD} mikefarah/yq:3 yq delete -i docker-compose.yml 'services[*].ports'
  # ...
```

Why do I not have the same behavior using `make` on a CI job and how can I solve this issue to avoid logic duplicate?

Comment: The error _make: wget: Operation not permitted_ means that there is a file `wget` on your `PATH` which is not an executable that can be invoked.  It is either not executable (doesn't have the `x` attribute set) or it's not a binary (it's a directory for example).

Comment: Could be different wget binaries being invoked. Try running `which wget` in the makefile and ci job, see if they match.

Comment: Well, it gives me `which: Operation not permitted` ha ha

Answer (score 0):

seccomp restricts the operations a docker container is allowed to do - for security reasons.

In the toml file for the gitlab runner add this to turn off seccomp:

```
  [runners.docker]
    security_opt = ["seccomp:unconfined"]
```

Normally this is an acceptable risk!

You can read more about trimming seccomp here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp